# How to upgrade typescript to version 1.7?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have **Visual Studio 2015** installed on my computer. Under the folder **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript**, I see two directories

- 1.0
- 1.6

When I use the command **tsc -v**, I see version **1.0.3.0**.

My questions are:

1. Is the version 1.0.3.0 really typescript version 1.6?
2. How can I update my computer to **Typescript 1.7**?

Comment: please mark the answer as a correct one if it helped you! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Version 1.7 is not released yet?!
Check the Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/

However you can update to the latest Version via http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download -> TypeScript for VS2015:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

This should install the latest Version of TypeScript correctly on your Computer.

Answer (score 3):

inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript delete all the folders exept 1.7

then run in terminal

```
tsc -v
```

if nothing 
run

```
  npm install -g typescript
```

and after

```
tsc -v
```

and you should see 1.7 version

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers say, TypeScript 1.7 (as of November 22nd, 2015) hasn't been released yet. However, the upcoming **Visual Studio 2015 Update 1**, which will include TypeScript 1.7, is scheduled to be released on November 30th. If you can wait another 8 days, there's your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System properties and edit the Path variable's value.

Replace the version of TypeScript from 1.0 to the highest version found in your machine.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\; - Old path in
>   path value
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7\; - New path to
>   be replaced

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't understand why after updating to latest typescript the version showing was still the old one. This fixed it.

Comment: where is this "system properties" you talk about?? why dont you eloborate this ?

Comment: Right click on "Computer" icon and click "Properties". (Or hit **Win Key + Pause**) then click _Advanced System Settings_ and _Environment Variables_ to open the Environment Variables dialog.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript 1.7 has not been released yet: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5624